# Is there some way to get more than Meta and Ctrl on Windows? Long time Emacs user wants Hyper/Super

Tags: windows, emacs, user-interface

I've used Emacs for years on Linux, and I have lots of personally useful keybindings I've put under <kbd>Hyper</kbd> and <kbd>Super</kbd>. Nowadays I'm using Emacs on Windows and am missing those extra keybindings.

Is there some way in Windows to get modifier keys other than <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>Meta</kbd>?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There are some settings mentioned in [this google-groups thread:](http://groups.google.com/group/gnu.emacs.help/browse_thread/thread/93ee43478903f273)

```
; setting the PC keyboard's various keys to Super or Hyper
(setq w32-pass-lwindow-to-system nil
      w32-pass-rwindow-to-system nil
      w32-pass-apps-to-system nil
      w32-lwindow-modifier 'super ;; Left Windows key
      w32-rwindow-modifier 'super ;; Right Windows key
      w32-apps-modifier 'hyper) ;; Menu key
```

Update: so, I actually *tried* the above code in my own Win32 emacs setup. Lo, it works! awkward demo follows:

```
(defun super-test ()
  (interactive)
  (message "Super"))

(defun hyper-test ()
  (interactive)
  (message "Hyper"))

(global-set-key [(super h)] 'super-test)
(global-set-key [(hyper h)] 'hyper-test)
```

Unless I've done something else funky, these work natively; I'm running GNU Emacs 23.0.60.1 (i386-mingw-nt5.1.2600) of 2008-08-19 on LENNART-69DE564 (patched)

Comment: This doesn't work for me on Windows 10. Is it possible to fix?

Comment: I tried to attach Win-z, which doesn't have any native shortcuts, but it doesn't work anyway.

Answer (score -1):

You may find this difficult, because Super (and, I believe, Hyper) are intercepted by the Windows Shell (explorer.exe) before they ever reach your app.

Comment: This is almost ancient history net-wise, but my answer seems to invalidate yours. Can you provide some scenarios where explorer.exe intercepts (and removes? or something?) these keys, or some sort of gloss to your answer?

Comment: @MichaelPaulukonis This whole thing is from so long ago that I have no idea what I was talking about.  Maybe I was wrong.  I have no idea.