# Linux: Mapping Windows key to M-x for the purpose of emacs usage

Tags: linux, emacs, windows-key

I am an emacs user (on linux laptop) looking to make better use of my keyboard settings.  The windows key is unused on my keyboard...  is there any way to map it to m-x?  This might make many emacs commands faster.

Thanks,

SetJmp

Comment: I'd actually like to set it to Hyper.

Comment: for windows users wondering, this is answered at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/356724/is-there-some-way-to-get-more-than-meta-and-ctrl-on-windows-long-time-emacs-user

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `xmodmap` to make it the `Menu` key, as in

```
keycode 115 = Menu
```

You will have to use `xev` to find out if the Windows key is key 115 on your keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

Just to provide a little more info, here's a link to a quick series of steps to remap the CapsLock Key in both [X](http://linuxcommando.blogspot.com/2008/03/remap-useless-caps-lock-key-in-x.html) and [Virtual Consoles](http://linuxcommando.blogspot.com/2008/03/remap-caps-lock-key-for-virtual-console.html):

The steps can be identically followed for Windows key or whatever else you may wish to remap.